# How to Get the Playable duration in react native video when the video is paused

Tags: react-native, react-native-video

I am using the react-native https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video library to play the videos in my mobile app.

Now I wanted to show the playable duration ( amount of video that is already loaded in the player) as you can see in the picture

[image]

To get the playable duration i am using the following method

```
  onProgress={this.onProgress.bind(this)}
```

Problem here is that this method only triggers when the video is playing ,this method is not called when the video is paused
so my question is is there any way i can get the playable duration when the video is paused

Comment: it will get triggered for each and every second. so store the value in some variable. after puasing, whatever value is there in the variable will be the played duration

Comment: @NabeelK onProgress onProgress this event is not triggered when the video is paused, i have seen some questions related to this on the react-native video https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video/issues/1504

Comment: The event will get triggered till u press pause button.store that progress in a variable. after u press pause the variable will have the last progress. I have done this please try and see

Comment: @NabeelK can you share the code snippet, how you have achieved it